# Download jpg from internet without error else load a template.jpg

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

I have a TImage which displays a JPG image from a folder. Each JPG image name is numerical (e.g. 5968.jpg) If the JPG image does not exist, i currently load a template JPG.

However, I would like to check the internet for it after checking the local folder

I know the URL and I just concatenate the image number and extension to it (e.g. 'http://www.myurl.com/images/' +  Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg')

I would like to download this image if it does not exist locally.

```
if FileExists(TagPath + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg') then
    imgTag.Picture.LoadFromFile(TagPath + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg')
   else
    imgTag.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Template.jpg');
```

How would I download the image (use idHTTP ?) to the TImage (imgTag). How would I handle any exception.

The flow should be as such, without any errors.

```
if FileExists locally, load image
else
 if fileEists on the internet load Image
  else
   Load the template
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdHTTP;

var
  FileName: string;
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  FileName := TagPath + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg';
  if not FileExists(FileName) then
  begin
    try
      Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
        try
          HTTP.Get('http://www.myurl.com/images/' + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg', Strm);
        finally
          HTTP.Free;
        end;
        Strm.Position := 0;
        Strm.SaveToFile(FileName);
      finally
        Strm.Free;
      end;
    except
      FileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Template.jpg';
    end;
  end;
  imgTag.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
end;
```

Comment: Hi remy, thanks, but i prety much need the part of downloading the image using idhttp, I was curious about the no internet connection and no file exists on the internet scenarios. If the file doesn't exist locally, then load from internet, but if can't load from internet, then load a template file - thanx

Comment: That's all included in the above code... The template file name is assigned to the `FileName` variable when the `TIdHTTP` fails to get the file from the given URL (if it doesn't already exist locally).

Comment: if their is no internet connection, your code crashes, instead of loading the template

Comment: All the exceptions are handled there, so what you probably see is the debugger message notifying you about the raised exception, but you won't see this message if you run your application without debugger. Anyway, if you click continue on that message, the program will continue to run.

Comment: Thats what i was doing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can resort to the standard [`TDownloadURL` action](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ExtActns_TDownLoadURL.html) in order to make a simple download of the internet and add this to your logic, something in the lines of:

```
uses
  ExtActns;

function TMyForm.TryDownloadFile(const AURL, AFileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  with TDownLoadURL.Create(nil) do
  try
    URL := AURL;
    Filename := AFileName;
    try
      ExecuteTarget(nil);
      Result := True;
    except
      ; //please, improve this handling specific exceptions
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.LoadFile(Index: Integer);
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName := TagPath + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg';
  if not FileExists(FileName) then
    if not TryDownlaodFile('http://www.myurl.com/images/' + Tags.Names[Index] + '.jpg', 
      FileName) then
      FileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Template.jpg';
  imgTag.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
end;
```

The shown code sin is that I eat any exception in the exception handler, and that's a bad practice, but I wrote this answer directly in this window and have no time to check which particular exceptions can be raised in the different failure scenarios with the action. It would be nice if you make that improvements and come back and contribute it to the community.

Comment: Your code downloads the image, but when the TImage tries to load it, it throws an error #53

Comment: mmm, I don't know what to say, I tried my method now with XE-XE3 and it works well, maybe a bug in the action in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

i ussually use this code to check is file exists on webserver

```
function CheckUrl(url: string): boolean;
var
  hSession, hfile, hRequest: hInternet;
  dwindex,dwcodelen: DWord;
  dwcode:array[1..20] of Char;
  res: PChar;
begin
  if Pos('http://', LowerCase(url)) = 0 then
    url := 'http://' + url;
  Result := False;
  hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if Assigned(hsession) then
  begin
    hfile := InternetOpenUrl(hsession, PChar(url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    dwIndex := 0;
    dwCodeLen := 10;
    HttpQueryInfo(hfile, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, @dwCode, dwCodeLen, dwIndex);
    res := PChar(@dwCode);
    Result := (res = '200') or (res = '302');
    if Assigned(hFile) then
      InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

and to download file you can use Jachguate answer

Comment: I need to determine if their is a connection first. This function will not work if there is no internet connection

Comment: if that who you need, you can use ping function first.